# One time database update to UI

Tags: html, codeigniter, websocket, real-time, reverse-ajax

There is one time update on database which is happening through webservice. When this update happens I need to reflect it on UI right away.

It's not a chatty application and this type of reverse update is rare.
What is the best way to achieve it?
I read about using Websockets, [pusher api](http://pusher.com/) and some Realtime.co. But not sure which one is latest, easy to use etc.

I have XAMPP stack over Codeigniter.